# How to tell automapper to skip mapping properties from source type if they are default values?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, automapper, dto

I have two types and I want to be able to ignore mapping the properties on the source instance into the destination instance in the case where the properties are set to a "default" value that I specify.  The only place the default value exists is as a piece of metadata above the type or in the constructor:

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue("")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I think that's an anti-pattern, because mappers are supposed to be dumb, and thus you might want to resist the temptation of putting too much logic inside them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ResolveUsing" method to configure a value using Reflection.
Alternatively, you can place the default values in your mapping configuration using the "UseValue" configuration method.

For example:

```
ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.ResolveUsing(GetDefaultValueAttributeContent));
```

Or:

```
ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.UseValue("Default Value"));
```

To add the condition, simply using a condition mapping that checks against the default value of the type:

```
.ForMember(destination => destination.Name,
    option => 
    {
        option.Condition(context => 
        {
            var src = context.InstanceCache.First().Value as SourceType;
            return src.Name == default(string);
        });

        option.ResolveUsing(GetDefaultValueAttributeContent);
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to set that generically for all properties instead of having to map to each one separately?

Comment: Technically yes...But you would again have to use reflection to grab the type of the source value.  There is no elegant solution for this and it likely wouldn't be worth the effort.